# Flutter not compiling application

Tags: flutter, compilation

I'm tryna compile application

```
Launching lib/main.dart on SM A705FN in debug mode...
../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.2/lib/src/io_client.dart:31:31: Error: Expected ')' before this.
      var ioRequest = (nawait _inner.openUrl(request.method, request.url))
                              ^^^^^^
../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.2/lib/src/io_client.dart:31:24: Error: The getter 'nawait' isn't defined for the class 'IOClient'.
 - 'IOClient' is from 'package:http/src/io_client.dart' ('../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.2/lib/src/io_client.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'nawait'.
      var ioRequest = (nawait _inner.openUrl(request.method, request.url))
```

NO errors on code.

Comment: `nawait`? most likely you typed `n` by mistake, it should be `await`

Comment: This is package. it isn't my code. I cleared pub cache repair 

And problem fixex

Comment: never mind, someone else typed `n` by mistake

Comment: Can you reply flutter pub cache repair and I will check it for right answer